# lubridate's force_tz doesn't recognize timezone

Tags: timezone, lubridate, posixct

I want to use `force_tz()` to change the time zone of my `ydm_hm()` object. My code:

```
force_tz(ydm_hm("2013-25-07 4:00am"), "Europe/Berlin")
```

So I tried with other timezones, e.g. `"CEST"`, but it only works with the default `"UTC"`. Here https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/man/force_tz.html it says, these should all be interpretable. The error message I get is:

*Error in C_force_tz(time, tz = tzone, roll) :
CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "Europe/Berlin"*

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What OS are you using?  Also, does this help? https://rdrr.io/r/base/timezones.html

Answer (score 1):

Hm, weird. I cannot replicate your error message (working on Win10):

```r
library(lubridate)

x <- ydm_hm("2013-25-07 4:00am")
x
#> [1] "2013-07-25 04:00:00 UTC"

force_tz(x, "Europe/Berlin")
#> [1] "2013-07-25 04:00:00 CEST"

force_tz(x, "etc/GMT-1")
#> [1] "2013-07-25 04:00:00 +01"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you're working on macOS, [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/928) post might help eventually. Also, in case you updated R currently, have you tried re-installing `lubridate` (c.f. [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/1065))?

Comment: Re-installing `lubridate` worked :)